# Gender of nouns that resemble actions

Tags: meaning, pronoun, gender

I want to clarify something about nouns that resemble actions in German. For instance, "Bücherlesen". First, what gender is ascribed to such nouns? Furthermore, if I were to say in reference to "Bücherlesen" something alongs the lines of "This is my favourite thing to do on weekends.", then what type of a pronoun should I be using to match "This"? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

While there are more ways of having nouns which resemble actions, you are specifically talking about substantivized verbs - nouns being produced by using the inifinitive form of a verb and making it a noun. Those are always neuter. In accordance to that, the pronoun to use would be *das* / *es*.

Answer (score 4):

*Substantivierte Verben* - verbs made nouns - are always built with the infinitive form and are always *neutral* (neuter). Notice that, like any proper noun in German, they are written capitalized:

> das Lesen - the reading
> das Schreiben - the writing
> das Laufen - the running

The grammatical gender of *Komposita* (nouns consisting of two or more nouns, like "Bücherlesen") is always that of the *last* part. In "Bücherlesen" this is not noticed, because both, "Buch" and "(das) Lesen" are *neutral*. But it is i.e. "der Essensrest" (the food leftover), because "der Rest" (remainder, residue) is *maskulin* whereas the "das Resteessen" (a meal consisting of leftovers, this is sometimes celebrated after big festivities including opulent meals) would be *neutral* because "das Essen" is the last part.

Comment: Note that *here* the nouns are not *proper nouns*.